# in struts2, how to show curent view (jsp page) in console

Tags: java, struts2

I want to debug my struts2 application.

How to show the current view (jsp page location with name) of current action in my eclipse console ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
System.err.println(this.getClass().getName());
```

?

-- sorry I just can't comment by myself (yet) --

> I want to know the jsp view page location and it's file name –  lovespring

That's exactly what you get:
if you invoke what i wrote, you'll get (e.g. in example.jsp)

```
org.apache.jsp.<Folder>.example_jsp
```

Comment: I want to know the jsp view page location and it's file name